# Why do I have inconsistent network issues with my laptop's wireless?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop, networking

I'm having trouble with my laptop Internet connection. It's patchy at best and resets or freezes a lot. The signal strength is also random. I thought it might be a driver issue but now I don't know.

- Three other computers using the same wireless network run well.
- I've switched out wireless routers so I don't think it's the router.
- I thought it might be the laptop's internal wireless card but I just bought an external USB network card and I'm still having problems.

**Specs**
Lenovo T-60p
Windows 7 Ultimate Edition
Patches/drivers are up to date

I only use one of the below at a time, disabling the other:

- Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG v. 13.3.0.137 (Internal wireless)
- Medialink Wireless-N USB 2.0 Adapter (USB wireless)

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like interference. Do you experience the same problems all over the house, or just in certain areas? Is there, like, a cordless phone or other wireless device nearby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've generally had poor experiences with wireless LAN. It just seems to be a slightly ropey technology.

One of the major problems is that the 2.4 GHz spectrum it uses is highly shared, with interference from (an example subset only):

- wireless baby monitors [these can blast out lots of power and can have poor spectral filtering so they are wide-band]
- cordless phones
- microwave ovens
- wireless doorbells
- anything Zigbee
- bluetooth stuff

And those are just a few off the top of my head. There's more.

It may also be that you see this only in some locations - inside buildings the attenuation of wireless signals is highly variable (factors of 20-30 dB... which equates to signal strength variation factors of 100x to 1000x) are quite normal.

You may be in a localized black spot in your building, but there may also be an interferer from a neighbor, or other device such as those listed.

If you find that moving the machine around in the building makes a difference then interference is the most likely culprit.

If moving around makes no difference then it may be something to do with the machine, its wireless adapter, or (co-incidences do happen) it may be that AND ALSO the new plug in adapter is also a bit dodgy.

Comment: Looks like location was the culprit. Thanks for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

On my HP laptop, I opened the bottom of the laptop, and found the (removable) wireless card slightly ajar. reseated it and problem disappeared..