# Wireless connection file-share becomes one-way

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop, smb, dell-latitude

We have two laptops - a Dell Latitude e5520 and a Dell Latitude e6520.  In both cases they are able to connect to the wireless router without incident.

Here's my problem:

When I try to access the laptops' file-share from my workstation, sometimes I can access and sometimes the device cannot be detected on the network.  Every time this happens I can still access the workstation's file-share from the laptop.  So the access is one-way.

When the laptop starts up, connection works both ways.  After awhile it becomes one-way (laptop to workstation only).  I can get the connection correct again by disabling and enabling the adapter.

From my workstation, I can see the laptop inside of Network in Windows Explorer; but if I try to connect to it it says `Windows cannot access \\mylaptop`.  So it is *findable* but not *accessible*.

If I plug in the ethernet cable then I have no problems, so the issue has to do with wireless.

- I've gone into the power settings for the adapter and told windows
  not to power off the adapter in order to save power; but this does
  not solve the situation.
- It's not a matter of signal strength either, because the wireless router is only one foot away...
- The connection seems to last anywhere between 10 to 20 minutes.  The laptop is not sleeping.
- It can't be a matter of a [loose chip connection because](https://superuser.com/questions/230683/why-do-i-have-inconsistent-network-issues-with-my-laptops-wireless?rq=1) if I disconnect and reconnect to the wireless signal it always works.
- It *never* loses the internet connection
- It *never* loses the ability to browse shares on workstations on the network
- I've updated the driver for the wireless adapter.
- In the IPv4 settings for the adapter, I have `Enable LMHOSTS lookup` enabled for `WINS`, and the `NetBIOS setting` is set to `Default`.
- I cannot ping the laptop from the workstation, but I can ping the workstation from the laptop - even with the firewall off, and even by ipaddress instead of computer-name. `Destination Host unreachable`

Here is the `ipconfig /all` from the laptop; it looks the same both before and after it loses it's fileshare connection (the ipconfig of the desktop basically looks the same except for the addresses and the adapter):

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : my.domain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : DW1501 Wireless-N WLAN Half-Mini Card
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.249(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, February 29, 2016 9:57:53 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, March 01, 2016 10:29:17 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.13
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.12
                                       192.168.2.7
   Primary WINS Server . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.7
   Secondary WINS Server . . . . . . : 192.168.1.12
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Is there something else I can try?

*[update]*

So I hooked up `WinMTR` on my desktop to ping the laptop continually, and the laptop's fileshare seems to stay connected, even for hours and hours, whereas without the constant pinging it semi-disconnects after less than a minute.  As long as the laptop is being continually pinged, it stays fully connected.  But if I stop `WinMTR` for a few minutes, then it loses the connected and I can't ping it anymore (although it can ping other machines).

However, if I join the laptop with TeamViewer, something jives and the fileshare and the pings start working.

Comment: Can you access it by IP address, or do you get the same error?

Comment: oh, that's a good question...  let me see...  I have to start it and then wait for it to forget...  I'll post back as soon as I have an answer.

Comment: No, it can't be found that way, either.  But it's the same as with using \\mycomputer - if I disconnect and reconnect to the wireless then it works for a time.

Comment: First, see if it pings. Second, try turning off the firewall.

Comment: No, I cannot ping the laptop from the workstation, but I can ping the workstation from the laptop - even with the firewall off, and even by ipaddress.  `Destination Host unreachable`

Comment: @allquixotic - Thanks for posting the bounty.

Comment: I have wireshark on my workstation, and have filtered with `ip.addr == 192.168.1.249`.  But what do I look for?

Comment: Could you post the results of `ipconfig /all` on both computers before and after the the file share stopped working,

Comment: Try to set [KeepConn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960471.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (not sure if it still applies to Windows 10). Also [these solutions](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/mapped-drive-gets-disconnected) on both computers.

Comment: @bgmCoder does this happen after a certain while of time? _15 minutes?_

Comment: @doenoe: That is exactly what is suggested in my above comment,

Comment: Both of my machines are Windows 7.  I don't have a `KeepConn` in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters ` on neither my workstation nor my laptop.  However `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters` has `autodisconnect` set to 15.

Comment: @doenoe It seems to happen in less than a minute; it's only on LAN access; internet is just fine all the time.

Comment: To be clear the windows or antivirus firewall is off right (also don't rule out a network/AP firewall). I have seen sporadic issues in a domain with NLA (Network Location Awareness) changing the location (Domain to Work or Public) & consequently switching the firewall profile from off to on

Comment: The firewalls in all three profiles are disabled on both machines.  There is no network firewall between the two devices - only a switch and the wireless router with no firewall enabled.

Comment: My second link has the advice of (1) Setting the hexadecimal value of autodisconnect to `ffffffff`, (2) Entering in elevated cmd the command `net config server /autodisconnect:-1` on both computers. (I am not sure if both methods are not synonym).

Comment: Can you post that as the solution?  I think it's working; I've been connected now for about 20 minutes.

Comment: It sounds more like a firewall of some sort, but this could also be caused by a duplicate IP address, especially if there is another device using the same address as your laptop.  Under normal circumstances Windows is generally good about warning you if that is the case.  Are there any other devices on your network, or perhaps more than one DHCP server?

Comment: No, I manage the dhcp server, and there is only one, and it reports no duplicates.  The laptop has a static ip address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be encountering a bad parameter in the Windows [AutoDisconnect](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960235.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) feature.

The last serious discussion on this subject by Microsoft that I found is
in the article
[How Autodisconnect Works in Windows NT and Windows 2000](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/138365) (!) :

> You can find the LAN `Autodisconnect` parameter in the registry under
>   the subtree HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE under the subkey:
>
> `\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`
>
> NOTE: The preceding entry must be located on the computer that has the
>   share or shares.
>
> The purpose is to disconnect idle sessions after a set number of
>   minutes. The number of minutes can be set at a command prompt using
>   the net config server command.
>
> For example, to set the Autodisconnect value to 30 minutes, you would
>   run the following command line:
>
> ```
> net config server /autodisconnect:30
> ```
>
> The valid value range is -1 to 65535 minutes at the command line. To
>   disable Autodisconnect set it to -1.
>
> Setting Autodisconnect to 0 does not turn it off and results in very
>   fast disconnects, within a few seconds of idle time.
>
> The registry does not allow you to add a -1 value. However, that
>   modification may be made at the command prompt with the following
>   command:
>
> ```
> net config server /autodisconnect:-1
> ```

I do not really agree with the last paragraph above, since in my opinion
setting the hexadecimal value of `autodisconnect` in the registry
to `ffffffff` will have the same effect as the above command -
avoiding disconnect for a few thousands years.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to setting it to `ffffffff` like that other than a power drain?  I don't know what was wrong before, the value was set to `15` which is the default.  It just wasn't working.  With this new setting everything works like a charm, though.

Comment: I don't think there is any disadvantage when a network-share stays connected for a longer time, and Windows doesn't use more power for maintaining it in its runtime tables. Windows won't enter sleep while a file stays open over the network, but then you wouldn't want it to.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Friend - I've had this problem for a long time and now it's resolved.